# "sample larger than population or is negative" but list contains more elements than sample size in list retrieved from url?

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, population

python 3: I am trying to code a bingo game which asks the user for 1-3 players, assigns each player a name, and then creates their Bingo card by choosing 25 elements from the list listOfStrings. the list contains 53 elements which are all strings. I am getting the error "ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative" but 25<53 ? is the size of my list incorrect or do I have to assign each element a number? not sure why this is happening. im new to programming so probably a simple mistake or miscomprehension

```
import urllib.request
import random
listOfStrings = []

def createList():
    try:
       with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.cs.queensu.ca/home/cords2/bingo.txt') as f:
           d = f.read().decode('utf-8')
           split= d.split("\n")
           listOfStrings = split
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print(e.reason)


def players(listOfStrings):
    noPlayers = input("How many players would like to play Bingo? Choose 1-3: ")
    if noPlayers == "1":
        name = input("What is the name of player 1? ")
        player1card = random.sample(list(listOfStrings), 25) 


createList()
players(listOfStrings)
print(player1card)
```

Comment: please let me know how I can make the question better if there's an issue

Comment: You should make `listOfString` global in `createList()` or return it from the function. Even better, do not initialize it globally at all - and you will see the _actual_ error message.